# Exact/Literal word or pattern match regex

Tags: c#, regex, wildcard

I am trying to match the patterns in a table with *user utterance*.

```
string userUtterance = "I want identification number for number of customers";

string pattern1 = "identification number";

string pattern2 = "tom";

string pattern3 = "id";
```

Desired results:

```
bool match1  =  regex.Ismatch(userUtterance, pattern1); // should match

if(match1 == true)
{
    // replace only the matched pattern in userUtterance
};

bool match2  =  regex.Ismatch(userUtterance, pattern2); // should not match

bool match3  =  regex.Ismatch(userUtterance, pattern3); // should not match
```

I would like a little advice on the use of regular expressions matching that syntax to restrict ambiguous matches and exactly match the literal words.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you setting `match1` to a true value after getting its value, also the line after you set it true you are testing if it is??

Comment: I have changed it. I would like to replace the only matched part in the user Utterance with different value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the *anchor* `\b` for word boundaries:

```
"\bonly these words\b"
```

This will match *only these words* in these sentences:

> Here are only these words baby.
>
> Here are "only these words" baby.
>
> Here are only these words, baby.
>
> Here are only these words.
>
> I said: 'only these words'.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of regex for the replacing you could just try this:

```
        string userUtterance = "I want identification number for number of customers";

        string pattern1 = "identification number";

        string pattern2 = "\btom \b";

        string pattern3 = "\bid \b";

        string replacement = "{YourWordHere}"

        string newuserUtterance = userUtterance.Replace(pattern1, replacement );

        bool match2 = Regex.IsMatch(newuserUtterance, pattern2); // should not match

        bool match3 = Regex.IsMatch(newuserUtterance, pattern3); // should not match
```

This will replace `pattern1` in the string `userUtterance` with your `replacement`

then test if the `tom` <= Note the space, is in the newly created string, then it will test if `id` <= again note the space, is in the new string.